# X has PDF: $g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sin x \text{ for } x \in (0, \pi)$ Find $\mathbb{P} (\sin^2X \leq \frac{1}{2})$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

The random variable $X$ has probability density function $g(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sin x \cdot y \to \text{  ,  with } y = 1 \text{ for: } x \in (0, \pi)$ and $y = 0$ elsewhere.

Find:

- $\mathbb{P} (\sin^2X \leq \frac{1}{2})$
- distribution of a random variable: max{ $\sin X, \frac{1}{2}$}

Now, I think know how to find distribution function (CDF) for $X$, but I don't know how to derive $\mathbb{P} (\sin^2X \leq \frac{1}{2})$ form that. Also, I have no idea how to determine the distribution function for max{ $\sin X, \frac{1}{2}$}.

Starting with the thing I suppose I know how to do - distribution function (CDF) for $X$:

$\mathbb{P} ( X \leq 0) = \int_{- \infty}^0 g(x) dx = 0$

$\mathbb{P} ( X \geq 0) = \int_{\pi}^{\infty} g(x) dx = 0$

for $t \in [0, \pi]$ we get that:
$$\mathbb{P} ( X \leq t) = \int_{- \infty}^{t} g(x) dx = \int_{0}^{t} g(x) dx = \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{2} \sin x = -\frac{1}{2} \cos x \Big|_{0}^{t} = -\frac{1}{2} \cos t$$

But then I get a function $\mathbb{P}$ that is monotonically increasing for $t \in (0, \pi)$ from value $- \frac{1}{2}$ to value $\frac{1}{2}$. And that seans off - that should be all posivie - am I right?

Comment: I think that there are some confusions in your question. Could you explain, what $g_x(t)$ is? So far, you have only defined a function $g$...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, you are right! I ment $g_x$ all the time. I will correct my post. Maybe there will be some confusions, still. I try to understand the matter the best I can.

Comment: Ok thx, I'll take a look when it is changed.

Comment: what do you mean by "For $g(x)$ we define $g_x(t)$ which is a function of upper limits (t) for unction $g(x)$"? Is $g_x(t)$ some sort of integral?

Comment: No, I thought that $g_x(t)$ is a function of t that I need to integrate to get CDF. And g(x) by itself is PDF. I might be wrong. @MushuNrek

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Perhaps I can clarify: if you have a probability density function (in this case $g$), then you get the probability $\mathbb P(a \leq X\leq b)$ by integrating the probability density: $\int_a^b g(x) dx$. No additional function is needed. Perhaps, you can solve it now! Please do edit the question once you've tried and if any doubts are left, I can have a look at it then :) @mathman12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first:
$$P\left(\sin^2(X)\leq 1/2\right)=P\left(\sin(X)\leq 1/\sqrt{2}\right)=2P\left(X\leq \arcsin(1/\sqrt{2})\right)\\
=\int_0^{\arcsin(1/\sqrt{2})} \sin(x) \, {\rm d}x = 1-1/\sqrt{2} \, .$$

For the second you are looking for a distribution function $f(y)$ for the random variable $Y=\max\{\sin(X),1/2\}$. That is, the probability to obtain the value $y$ in an interval ${\rm d}y$ about $y$ is given by $f(y) \, {\rm d}y$. On the other hand you can think of the expression $\delta(y-Y){\rm d}y$ as being $1$ whenever $y=Y$ and $0$ otherwise ($\delta$ being the Dirac delta-function). Then you sum over all $x$ the expression $g(x)\delta(y-Y){\rm d}y$, which gives a contribution to the prob. $f(y){\rm d}y$ whenever $y=Y$ and no contribution otherwise, which is (again) the probability to obtain $y$ within the interval ${\rm d}y$, thus
$$f(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \delta(y-Y) \, {\rm d}x=\frac12\int_{0}^\pi \sin(x) \delta\left(y-\max\{\sin(x),1/2\}\right) \, {\rm d}x \\
=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin(x) \delta\left(y-\max\{\sin(x),1/2\}\right) \, {\rm d}x \\
=\int_{0}^{\pi/6} \sin(x) \delta\left(y-1/2\right) \, {\rm d}x + \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} \sin(x) \delta\left(y-\sin(x)\right) \, {\rm d}x \\
= \left(1-\sqrt{3}/2\right)\delta(y-1/2) + \left[1/2 \leq y \leq 1\right] \tan(\arcsin(y)) \\
= \left(1-\sqrt{3}/2\right)\delta(y-1/2) + \left[1/2 \leq y \leq 1\right] \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} \, .$$
Here $[\cdot]$ is the iversion bracket.

From $f(y)$ you get $P(Y\leq y)$ by integrating from $0$ to $1/2\leq y\leq 1$, i.e.
$$P(Y\leq y)=\int_0^y f(t) \, {\rm d}t = 1-\sqrt{3}/2 + \sqrt{3}/2 - \sqrt{1-y^2}=1-\sqrt{1-y^2}\,.$$

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't be that dependent on t? Also, what did I do wrong that my $\mathbb{P}(X \leq t)$ is partly negative? @Diger

Comment: @MushuNrek do you know where the 2nd and 3rd equations come from? I mean, why probability becomes $2 \times$ probability and why the last equation works? What is X out there? Is $X = \frac{1}{2} \cos t$?

Comment: It is not negative you missed the boundary at $x=0$ giving a term of $1/2$. Factor 2 comes from symmetry about $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: @Diger oh, so you integrate $g(x)$ with boundaries taken by transformations on initial problem. That's why the $\frac{1}{2}$ before $sinx$ disappears. Where did $2$ come from in the first place? I mean you use some king of symmetry? Is that correct that the integral is only sensible since $\arcsin(1/ \sqrt{2}) \leq \pi$?

Comment: The problem is that $\arcsin(x) \leq \pi/2$, so when $\sin(x)\leq 1/\sqrt{2}$ either $x\leq \arcsin(1/\sqrt{2})$ or $x\geq \pi - \arcsin(1/\sqrt{2})$, but the contribution from the latter case is the same as in the first case, due to the symmetry of the distr. function about $x=\pi/2$ giving a factor of $2$.

Comment: @MushuNrek: Actually I did answer on these things in the comments...

Comment: Ohh, I get it now, thank you. What about the integration? You integrate in that interval the function $g(x)$, right? Function $g(x)$ gives larrger values when integrated over larger sets over $(0, \pi)$ and the set that you are integration over is more narrow. @Diger

Comment: Are you still in the first case, at the step with the integration? You can use your formula $P(X\leq t) = \frac12 (1-\cos(t))$ and $\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: I get it now. I didn't know about that trigonometric property. Without it, it would be impossible to evaluate the integral to that simpler form, right (I mean, there is no other way)? Now I get the part a) of that question and go to part b). In our classes we have something like indicator function. Can dirac delta function be thought of as indicator function?

Comment: The Iversion bracket takes the role of the indicator function. It may be possible that your teacher did not expect you to take the detour over the distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

$Y = \max({\sin X, 1/2})$

$P(Y \leq y) = P(\max({\sin X, 1/2}) \leq y) = P(\sin X \leq y, 1/2 \leq y)$

For $y < 1/2$, $P(Y \leq y) = 0$

For $1 \geq y \geq 1/2$, $P(Y \leq y) = P(\sin X \leq y) = P(X \leq \sin^{-1}(y))$

From the given PDF of $X$, you can conclude $P(X \leq x) = {1 \over 2} (1 - \cos x)$

Thus, you get $P(Y \leq y) = 2P(X \leq \sin^{-1}(y)) = (1- \cos\sin^{-1}(y)) $ for $1 \geq y \geq 1/2$

Comment: You are missing a factor of $2$, because $P(\sin(X)\leq y) \neq P(X\leq \arcsin(y))$.